# How can I find commits which contain credentials/passwords with git log

Tags: git, diff, credentials

So, I have a repository and suspicions that someone accidentally commited credentials into it

I need to find all commits which contains my credentials: `tiWEythzNEX8N3sktiWEythzNEX8N3sk`

Let's see some commits. [There is small repo to reproduce](https://github.com/YegorZaremba/sandbox/tree/find-credentials-git-log)

Use command `git log --oneline -n 10`

```sh
963f080 (HEAD -> find-credentials-git-log) feat(3309): add middleware
b83a41f fix(3309): rm credentials
70ec8dc bug: ooops I show my credentials
895937f feat(3309): add server
534792d feat(3309): add types
9cce5c9 feat(3309): add position entity
```

Now lets see git diff of `70ec8dc bug: ooops I show my credentials` commit

Use command `git show 70ec8dc`

```sh
commit 70ec8dc914609d50bd0ef3c0b420db0b7a4aa7f5
Author: Yegor <mail@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 19 12:21:38 2019 +0300

    bug: ooops I show my credentials

diff --git a/typeorm/3309/startServer.ts b/typeorm/3309/startServer.ts
index 0f1c9bd..b3bd09e 100644
--- a/typeorm/3309/startServer.ts
+++ b/typeorm/3309/startServer.ts
@@ -45,7 +45,7 @@ export const startServer = async () => {
         prefix: redisSessionPrefix
       }),
       name: 'offerhub',
-      secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
+      secret: 'tiWEythzNEX8N3sktiWEythzNEX8N3sk', // My credentials
       resave: false,
       saveUninitialized: false,
       cookie: {
```

I need to find all commits which `git diff` contains this text/credentials `tiWEythzNEX8N3sktiWEythzNEX8N3sk`. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git log --oneline -S 'tiWEythzNEX8N3sktiWEythzNEX8N3sk'
```

See the doc [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Sltstringgt).